# Stripe payment example is not displaying

Tags: javascript, runtime-error, stripe-payments

I am trying to create a really simple example of using Stripe payments.

This is my code:

```js
// Create a Stripe client
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_XSHE4IYLLy9qCPe7lW7pK4ZE');

// Create an instance of Elements
var elements = stripe.elements();

// Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
// (Note that this demo uses a wider set of styles than the guide below.)
var style = {
base: {
  color: '#32325d',
  lineHeight: '24px',
  fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
  fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
  fontSize: '16px',
  '::placeholder': {
    color: '#aab7c4'
  }
},
invalid: {
  color: '#fa755a',
  iconColor: '#fa755a'
}
};

// Create an instance of the card Element
var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

// Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>
card.mount('#card-element');

// Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
if (event.error) {
  displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
} else {
  displayError.textContent = '';
}
});

// Handle form submission
var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();

stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
  if (result.error) {
    // Inform the user if there was an error
    var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
    errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
  } else {
    // Send the token to your server
    stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
  }
});
});
```

```css
.StripeElement {
background-color: white;
padding: 8px 12px;
border-radius: 4px;
border: 1px solid transparent;
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #e6ebf1;
-webkit-transition: box-shadow 150ms ease;
transition: box-shadow 150ms ease;
}

.StripeElement--focus {
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #cfd7df;
}

.StripeElement--invalid {
border-color: #fa755a;
}

.StripeElement--webkit-autofill {
background-color: #fefde5 !important;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="/charge" method="post" id="payment-form">
      <div class="form-row">
        <label for="card-element">
          Credit or debit card
        </label>
        <div id="card-element">
          <!-- a Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
        </div>

        <!-- Used to display form errors -->
        <div id="card-errors"></div>
      </div>

      <button>Submit Payment</button>
    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

I followed the example from [Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/elements).

This is the error that I got from the Javascript console:

```
Uncaught Error: The selector you specified (#card-element) applies to no DOM elements that are currently on the page.
Make sure the element exists on the page before calling mount().
     at new t (js.stripe.com/:1)
     at t.value (js.stripe.com/:1)
```

Based on the error, I think the Stripe JavaScript could not find any `#card-element`, but it is there.

This could be a dumb question, but this is my first time using Stripe, so it would be great if someone could help me. Thank you so much.

Comment: Is there somewhere in particular that you are getting stuck? From looking at your code it looks like you still need to define `stripeTokenHandler` as referenced by `stripeTokenHandler(result.token);` --- there's a sample here https://stripe.com/docs/elements#submit-token

Comment: @duck i just followed their example exactly. I edited my post show u can see the errors. Thanks much

Comment: hmm, if you're getting a 'no DOM element' error, yeah looks like you're loading the JS before `#card-element` exists on the page. Take a look at an example here http://jsbin.com/dukecivela/edit?html,output

Comment: @duck Thanks. It works now. You were right about that. but I can include my js library at the end of the page but i have never write my js script at the end of the page. Is that ok ?

Comment: Sure, @trinhdh, you can load your JS at the end, or you can wrap your code in `$(document).ready` (JQuery) or ` `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { });` so it won't execute until content is loaded. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded

Comment: Check out the demo app and download the code to accept payments and subscriptions with all payment methods with Stripe's newest product, Payment Element --> https://techtolia.com/Stripe/New/

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Don't add the script in the head, instead, add it right before you close the body.

```
<html lang= "en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/charge" method="post" id="payment-form">
            <div class="form-row">
                <label for="card-element">
                    Credit or debit card
                </label>
                <div id="card-element">
                <!-- a Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
                </div>
                <!-- Used to display form errors -->
                <div id="card-errors"></div>
            </div>
            <button>Submit Payment</button>
        </form>
        <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Putting your script at the bottom ensures that the DOM is rendered prior to executing the script, so that'll do the trick!

Comment: Once I move it to body, I run into Stripe is not defined for the rest of my JS Code

Answer (score 13):

Put your script after the html from,

```
 <form></form>
 //after your stripe form put stripe script 
 <script></script>
```

As below

```
<style type="text/css">
    * {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-variant: normal;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #E6EBF1;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

form {
  width: 480px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.group {
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 7px 14px 0 rgba(49,49,93,0.10),
              0 3px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

label {
  position: relative;
  color: #8898AA;
  font-weight: 300;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: block;
}

.group label:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #F0F5FA;
}

label > span {
  width: 20%;
  text-align: right;
  float: left;
}

.field {
  background: transparent;
  font-weight: 300;
  border: 0;
  color: #31325F;
  outline: none;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  cursor: text;
  width: 70%;
  height: 40px;
  float: right;
}

.field::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #CFD7E0; }
.field::-moz-placeholder { color: #CFD7E0; }
.field:-ms-input-placeholder { color: #CFD7E0; }

button {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  background: #666EE8;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 7px 14px 0 rgba(49,49,93,0.10),
              0 3px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 0;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 38px;
  outline: none;
}

button:focus {
  background: #555ABF;
}

button:active {
  background: #43458B;
}

.outcome {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 8px;
  min-height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}

.success, .error {
  display: none;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.success.visible, .error.visible {
  display: inline;
}

.error {
  color: #E4584C;
}

.success {
  color: #666EE8;
}

.success .token {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 13px;
}
</style>

<form action="subscription.php" method="post">
  <div class="group">
    <label>
      <span>Name</span>
      <input name="cardholder-name" class="field" placeholder="Jane Doe" />
    </label>
    <label>
      <span>Phone</span>
      <input class="field" placeholder="(123) 456-7890" type="tel" />
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <label>
      <span>Card</span>
      <div id="card-element" class="field"></div>
    </label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Pay $25</button>
  <div class="outcome">
    <div class="error" role="alert"></div>
    <div class="success">
      Success! Your Stripe token is <span class="token"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var stripe = Stripe('YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY');
    var elements = stripe.elements();

var card = elements.create('card', {
  style: {
    base: {
      iconColor: '#666EE8',
      color: '#31325F',
      lineHeight: '40px',
      fontWeight: 300,
      fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
      fontSize: '15px',

      '::placeholder': {
        color: '#CFD7E0',
      },
    },
  }
});

card.mount('#card-element');
function setOutcome(result) {
  var successElement = document.querySelector('.success');
  var errorElement = document.querySelector('.error');
  successElement.classList.remove('visible');
  errorElement.classList.remove('visible');

  if (result.token) {
    // Use the token to create a charge or a customer
    // https://stripe.com/docs/charges
    successElement.querySelector('.token').textContent = result.token.id;
    successElement.classList.add('visible');
  } else if (result.error) {
    errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
    errorElement.classList.add('visible');
  }
}

card.on('change', function(event) {
  setOutcome(event);
});

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = document.querySelector('form');
  var extraDetails = {
    name: form.querySelector('input[name=cardholder-name]').value,
  };
  stripe.createToken(card, extraDetails).then(setOutcome);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 7):

For anyone else with this same problem - the code snippet in Stripe's docs is incomplete. So the suggested fixes above may in fact be necessary to ensure proper order of operations, but the whole thing won't work unless you define a stripeTokenHandler method.

Stripe's docs define the method (further down the page) as:

```
function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
  // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
  var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
  var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
  form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

  // Submit the form
  form.submit();
}
```

Comment: var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
is returning 'undefined'

Comment: What does your form tag look like? In the Stripe doc (and OP's code) it is: <form action="/charge" method="post" id="payment-form">

Comment: yes. <form action="/charge" method="post" id="payment-form">

Answer (score 1):

Stripe.js renders the inputs for credit card number, expiration, CVC in iFrames. You cannot create these or get at them with JavaScript. You can however style the containers as you want which will enable you to get pretty close matching to the UI of your website - Bootstrap, MDC-Web, or whatever.

If your elements are not displaying, try the below to get started.

```
<div class="stripe-custom-element">
    <label for="stripe-card">Card Number</label>
    <div class="" id="stripe-card"></div>
</div>
<div class="stripe-custom-element">
    <label for="stripe-exp">Expiration</label>
    <div class="" id="stripe-exp"></div>
</div>
<div class="stripe-custom-element">
    <label for="stripe-cvc">CVC</label>
    <div class="" id="stripe-cvc"></div>
</div>

var cardNumberElement = doc.getElementById("stripe-card");
var cardExpiryElement = doc.getElementById("stripe-exp");
var cardCvcElement = doc.getElementById("stripe-cvc");

var cardNumber = elements.create('cardNumber', {});
var cardExpiry = elements.create('cardExpiry', {});
var cardCvc = elements.create('cardCvc', {});

cardNumber.mount(cardNumberElement);
cardExpiry.mount(cardExpiryElement);
cardCvc.mount(cardCvcElement);        

registerElements([cardNumber, cardExpiry, cardCvc]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be be late, but this worked for me , make sure to add the charge.js script below the stripe script , also, add them before the closing body tag

```
<html lang= "en">
    <head>
      
    
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="/charge" method="post" id="payment-form">
            <div class="form-row">
                <label for="card-element">
                    Credit or debit card
                </label>
                <div id="card-element">
                <!-- a Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
                </div>
                <!-- Used to display form errors -->
                <div id="card-errors"></div>
            </div>
            <button>Submit Payment</button>
        </form>
        <script type ="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
        <script src="charge.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```